# How to use splint on Linux Ubuntu for C programs?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, splint

I know splint is to issue warning messages about problems in C programs.

I installed it on my Ubuntu using 'sudo apt-get install splint'.

How do I use it on a C program or programs?

Comment: Perhaps start by reading [the manual](http://www.splint.org/manual/)? Or please specify what in particular you don't understand after reading that.

Comment: SPLint is not to fix warning messages(You have to fix the warnings shown by SPLint). It is a static code analyzer which will inform you about probable malfunction of your program.You should read its manual to better understand what it does.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the following C program in a file called `test.c` you can then use `splint` to perform a static analysis on the source to find possible problems.

The source code to put into the file test.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 100; 
    int b[8];

    printf("Hello c\n");
    b[8] = 100; // error

    return 0;
}
```

The command line used to run `splint` against the C source file to check for problems.

```sh
$ splint test.c +bounds -paramuse -varuse
```